# Customize login screen

Tags: 14.10, themes, login-screen

How can I customize my Ubuntu login screen like the one below? As I've already googled most solutions only change the background picture of the login screen not its structure and behaviour.

[image]

My current Ubuntu is 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)

I took this picture from [here](http://www.rawcomputing.co.uk/linux/welcome.html).

Comment: It might help us to help you if you were to [edit] your question and include the source of the login screen you posted.

Comment: @ElderGeek Edited.

Comment: That used to be the login screen waaay back in 8.x days, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the light-dm-webkit greeter. You can find packages [here.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm-webkit-greeter) The current version as of this writing is 0.1.2-0ubuntu2 and it appears it's available in the universe repository as well so you can install it through the software center:

[image: light-dm]

You'll need it to develop a [face browser theme](https://code.launchpad.net/~and471/lightdm-webkit-greeter/facebrowser-theme) to arrive at your desired solution but this should help you get started.